# How do I make my sites logo smaller?

Tags: logo

My sites logo is far to big I have tried changing the overall image size in photoshop however it doesn't help.

http:bentleyandhudson.com

Comment: The image tag says it's 3000 pixels wide, when you said you changed the size in photoshop, did you re-upload in WP or did you download resize and upload straight to the file system?

Comment: It might be helpful if you could provide the contents of your themes (or child themes) `header.php` file so we can see why the image tag is set to ~3067px by 986px

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question isn't really WordPress specific it's more an image editing or CSS question.

Firstly, your logo image size is incredibly large and there's no need for it whatsoever - you should resize it so that it's the size that you would like it actually displayed.

It looks like you're using a GoDaddy WordPress theme which is partly the problem too as it's explicitly setting the size of your image (`<img>`) element to 3067px X 986px and I've no idea at all why it would do this...

But, in order to help you, here's some CSS code that you'll need to enter in your themes CSS options or in your child themes style.css file to alter the size of the logo image:

```
.site-title-wrapper {
    width: 480px; /* Change this to whatever width you want */
    float: none; /* This stops the image being 'floated' to the left */
    margin: 0 auto; /* This centers the image */
}
```

Hope this helps!